# How to handle different Library Search Paths with Xcode and Git?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, git, path

I am working on an app with a friend.

We use git (private) as versioning system. The problem we face is that Xcode (5.1 DP2) gives this warning: "Apple Mach-O Linker Warning - Directory not found for ..."

[image]

The reason for this warning is that Xcode cannot find the path from my friend on my hard drive.

So my question is how to handle different absolute paths for the "Library Search Path" in Xcode in general when working with a team?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `SRCROOT` build setting. For example, add the following to Library Search Paths:

```
$(SRCROOT)/Libraries/MyLibrary
```

Full docs on Xcode build settings are [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Reference/XcodeBuildSettingRef/0-Introduction/introduction.html).