# Issue while linking static library in c

Tags: c, gcc, linker, static-libraries

I am learning to use Static libraries in C-language using XCode. I have created a basic math library with header and definition files and compiled it. **libmymath.a** is generated.

I have created a basic application with **main.c** to use this library.
I did following 2 steps to link and use static library:

1. In **Build Settings -> Header Search Paths** , I have added the path for libmymath.h file.
2. In **Build Phases** , I have added the path for **libmymath.a** to **Link Binary with Libraries**.

But on compiling, I got the error -

> ld: library not found for -lmymath
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see >invocation)

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "libmymath.h"

int main(int argc, const char * argv[] )
{

double r = 4.0;
double n = 5.0;
printf("Hello %.2f world",r);
//printf ("Radius %.2f, area is %.2f \n", r, CircleArea(r));
//printf ("Radius %.2f, circumference is %.2f \n", r, CircleCircum(r));
//printf ("%.2f to the power of 2 is %.2f \n", n, PowerOf2(n));
//printf ("%.2f to the power of 3 is %.2f \n", n, PowerOf3(n));

return 0;
}
```

I have cleaned the build and restarted it but still it is not working. How could I solve this issue?

I know that there are questions similar to this in stack overflow but I couldn't find a direct answer for my issue.

Comment: Nt familiar with XCode, but I would think there should be some "Library path" settings in addition to specifying the library names to be linked with.

Comment: I have already included the library path in  'Link Binary with Libraries'

Comment: I am seeing on the image in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20601558/how-to-handle-different-library-search-paths-with-xcode-and-git) that there is a "Library search path" right below the  "Header search path".

Comment: "I have already included the library path in 'Link Binary with Libraries'". No you haven't. You've told the linker to link `libmymath.a` but not told it any directory in which to look for that file: that's a *library path*, and is not the same as an *include path*, where the *compiler* looks for *header files*.

Comment: Thank you, adding path to `Library Search Path` solved my problem :)  @all